# Is there a way to output all of the variable names in a object?

Tags: java

I want to output all of my variable names in a object, e.g. "id, firstname, lastname". I do not want the values of the variables, I only want the variable name. Is there a way of accessing the variable names?

I've tried using reflection and fields. When I tried to use it, it prints out all of the variables in the class. Rather than printing out all the attribute names in a object.

```
public void printFieldNames()
{
    Field[] fields = ClassName.class.getDeclaredFields();
    //gives no of fields
    System.out.println(fields.length);         
    for (Field field : fields) 
    {
    //gives the names of the fields
    System.out.println(field.getName());  
    }
}
```

I want the output of all the attribute names in a object, but the output I can only get is the class variables.

Comment: Where is your object? and what's wrong it using regular getters to display properties?

Comment: *I only want the variable name* and *but the output I can only get is the class variables*... can you **please** clarify this seeming paradox?

Comment: Do you mean you want something like this?
class Pair
{
int a,b;
Pair(int a,int b)
{
this.a=a;
this.b=b;
}
}
and when an object of Pair is called, you want a,b to be displayed?

Comment: *example "id, firstname, lastname*" but where is the class code to complete this example? you write of variables, fields, attributes, ... that is all very confusing.  "*it prints out all of the variables*' NO, it prints the **name** of all **fields**  "*Rather then printing out all the attribute names*" what are attributes?

Comment: You seem to be using terminology slightly strangely.  What do you mean by "attribute names in an object"?  How is this different from "class variables"?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a mix of notions here (unless I'm missing the purpose of the question by myself).

Java is a language where all data fields must be declared when you "describe" during the "code-time" the objects that will be created during runtime so that the compiler will have this information.

Creating a class is exactly the way of doing this.

There is no concept of "expando" in java, or dynamic properties definitions. Everything is strict, everything is statically typed.

So say you have class:

```
  public class MyClass {
     private Integer foo;
     private String bar; 
     // constructor, methods, etc.
  }
```

This means that all the instances of this class will have these two fields. You can make the field static so that it will be shared among instances, you can change its visibility to fiddle with encapsulation, but that's it.

It impossible to do the following (unlike in some other languages):

```
  MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
  myClass.aNewField = 42;
```

Such a code won't even compile

This leaves you with reflection based approach that you've already tried and I believe for this class you were able to see "foo" and "bar" printed. 
You can **query** all the structure of the class (which methods does it have, which data fields, their names, their types, access modifiers, metadata (annotations) and so forth) with reflection.

Given this information, maybe you want to provide a better example of what do you want to achieve with a real class definition and expected / actual output.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is well explained by [`Mark Bramnik`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57566640/5703813) that why can't we store variable names in java object. As Compiler do not allows to create variable with same name already declared in same scope hence variable names are unique in scope. So you can collect variable names in `Set<String>`.

```
Set<String> fieldNames = Arrays.stream(ClassName.class.getDeclaredFields())
                .map(Field::getName)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

fieldNames.forEach(System.out::println);
```